# python appscript for macOS

Tags: python, excel, macos, applescript, py-appscript

I am trying to use python package appscript to control applications in my MacBook. Unfortunately I am really confused.

For example, I am trying to control one of my excel files. I want to get the position and scroll to certain roll. Here is my code

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from appscript import *

file = app('Microsoft Excel').documents[u'test.csv']
position = file.window.left_position()
print position
```

The code is only trying to get the position but it is not working. I download the ASDictionary to check the command but I still can not fix it. Here is the screenshot of the command:

[image]

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel’s Apple event (“AppleScript”) support is atypical and quirky.

1. Avoid using `documents`; it doesn’t work correctly. Use `workbooks` instead.
2. Workbooks don’t have a `window` property. They do, however, have `windows` elements (since you can view a workbook in more than one window).

Corrected Python code:

```
wb = app('Microsoft Excel').workbooks[u'test.csv']
position = wb.windows[1].left_position()
print(position)
```

Or, in AppleScript:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell workbook "test.csv"
        get left position of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: thank you so much. do you mind telling me how to get window id? I try "wb.windows[1].id()" but it is not working

Comment: Unlike most scriptable apps, Excel’s `window` doesn’t have an `id` property. You can only reference Excel windows by index or name.